# How to move points proportionally to keep edge flow good?

Tags: modeling

So lets say we have 3 points A, B, and C.

I want to be able to move C, keeping the points between AB and BC proportional.

How would one go about doing this?

This would help a lot with keeping my edge flow good.

Comment: keep points between AB and BC proportional *to what*? Can you clarify what you mean? Do you mean keep edges AB and BC proportional to each other? If so, then you move C in circle around B, because AB does not change.

Comment: Please show a screen capture or gif to help clarify your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Presumably you mean that you want to move B, keeping AB proportional to BC?

If you want to maintain the plane defined by ABC: Select A and B.  <kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>s</kbd> snap cursor to selection.  <kbd>.</kbd>change pivot point to cursor.  Select C.  <kbd>s</kbd> scale, confirm.

Do you want to move into a different plane than that defined by ABC?  Select A and C.  <kbd>f</kbd> create an edge between them.  Snap cursor to selection.  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>space</kbd> create custom orientation.  <kbd>x</kbd> delete your edge if you want.  Change pivot point to cursor and select B.  <kbd>r</kbd><kbd>y</kbd><kbd>y</kbd> rotate constrained to custom Y axis.  Rotate into the plane you want and confirm.

Note that your cursor is in the same spot for both scale and rotate, you can easily do a bit of scaling then a bit of rotating then a bit of scaling.

Comment: kbd formatting for keyboard keys please. E.g. <kbd>F</kbd>.

Comment: Why?  Are you having trouble understanding what I'm writing?

Comment: No, it's just the standard way of formatting keyboard keys here and helps them stand out from the text.

Comment: @RayMairlot Okay, this time because you're nice, but I doubt I will in the future-- it is tedious and would lead me to provide fewer kb shortcuts with my answers, which is counterproductive.  I certainly have no beef with anyone who ever wants to edit them in.

Comment: @Nathan you can use little script made somewhere in meta to help you adding <kbd> tag. We all are doing this without excuses. To keep some level of quality of this site the sacrifices are needed. As far as I know nobody accepts (officially) sacrifices from virgins so putting <kbd>, using text formatting and adding nice pictures/gifs should be suffice.

Comment: @cgslav See meta: https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2509/kbd-shortcuts-and-unwillingness-to-comply

Answer (score 0):

Consider

- scaling 3 vertices first which preserves proportion with the correct mode of scale (center point)
- then translating by grabbing.

Answer (score 0):

As for more real life example you can use add-on **LoopTools** (shipped with Blender, highly recommended).

It is working better with denser mesh than 3 vertices.

You can select your edge than press <kbd>W</kbd> > ***LoopTools*** > ***Space***.

The **LoopTools** will try to space evenly your vertices along selected edge. It's not perfect, but for a good reason. Spacing 100% evenly could deform edge too much. If you want it to be spaced 100% evenly, you can repeat adding **Space**.

On this example you can see two edges. Edge '**A**' - original and '**B**' - after **Space**.

[image: example]